How do I stop my NVIDIA to be used by the secondary user?
Good morning,
I have an Asus Vivobook K6500ZC laptop with Intel HUD GPU and NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU.
I'm looking for help regarding an unexpected usage of the NVIDIA GPU.
I currently share the laptop with multiple people, and we often lock the screen and switch to another user account without completely logging out the previous account, so that apps would be still open in the background.
When switching to the secondary account, some primary account processes are moved to the NVIDIA GPU, causing the GPU to turn on and consequently drain more batter.
Below is the list of some apps that are running on background on the primary user, and are listed as running on NVIDIA GPU

logonui.exe
startmenuexperiencehost.exe
msedgewebview2.exe
whatsapp.exe
dolbyaccess.exe
taskmgr.exe


NOTE: By using the two accounts SEPARATELY (i.e. logging out the account before switching to the next account) none of these processes are running on the NVIDIA GPU.
Similarly, from the 2nd user session, when I force logout the 1st user via task manager, the NVIDIA activity app gets cleared
Additional INFO:

Bios 303
Laptop restored to factory condition
Test carried out both in factory conditions (without performing any updates) and after executing the Microsoft and My Asus updates.

ASUS support didn't want to help, saying this is an expected behavior.
Any help on how to always use the integrated GPU?
